# Resolve generic type in IntelliJ plugin codecheck

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-inspections

I write an *IntelliJ Plugin* that performs some checks on *Java code*. 
For one of these checks I need to know the **type of a generic field**.
Example:

```java
// Model classes B and D
public class B {
    void doB() {

    }
}

public class D extends B {
    void doD() {

    }
}

// Classes that use the model classes
public class Base<T extends B> {

    protected List<T> list;

    private void test() {
        list.get(0).doB();
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base<D> {

    private void test() {
        list.get(0).doD();
    }
}
```

The class `Base` contains a list with a generic parameter `T` which is accessed from class `Base` and its derived class `Derived`.

I have an annotator (might be changed to LocalInspection) that checks the access to `list` in both classes.
This is what I have so far (I left out type- and null-checks for simplicity):

```java
public class GenAnno implements Annotator {
    @Override
    public void annotate(@NotNull PsiElement element, @NotNull AnnotationHolder holder) {

        if (element instanceof PsiReferenceExpression) {

            PsiReferenceExpression refExpr = (PsiReferenceExpression)element;
            PsiElement target = refExpr.resolve();

            PsiField field = (PsiField) target;
            PsiClassType fieldType = (PsiClassType) field.getType();

            PsiClassType itTyp = (PsiClassType) PsiUtil.extractIterableTypeParameter(fieldType, false);
            PsiClass cl = itTyp.resolve();

            PsiTypeParameter tpara = (PsiTypeParameter) cl;
            JvmReferenceType[] refTypes = tpara.getBounds();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the lowest required type of the generic in context of the usage (the `PsiReferenceExpression`). Or regarding my example from above:

- At the access to `list` in class `Base`, I want type `B`
- At the access to `list` in class `Derived`, I want type `D`

But I always get `PsiType:B` in the variable `refTypes`. What do I have to change to get the expected types?

Small background info: I want to check if types, used by reflection, contain the field or method.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the type of `list.get(0)` (i.e like `refExpr.getType()`), it will return the `D` PsiTpe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this only works in one of the 2 cases. It gives `D` as expected in class `Derived` but `T` instead of `B` in `Base`. In other words, when it is a specific class, I need the class. When it is constrained, it need the constraint.